# JavaScript/Nightwatch.js - Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, web, automation, nightwatch.js

I am trying to write at test case in java script.

Code:

`'should verify login dropdown is not visible after clicking away': function (browser) {
        var welcome = browser.page.welcome();
        welcome.navigate()
        .waitForElementVisible('@loginButton', 5000)
        welcome.click('@loginButton')
        welcome.expect.element('@logoutButton').text.to.equal('Logout').after(500)
        welcome.click('@usersButton')
        welcome.element('@logoutButton').to.not.be.present
    },`

For the last line I am getting an error like below. No idea why to.not.be.present is not recognized while it's described in NightWatch documentation. Any advice from anyone ?

`TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.should verify login dropdown is not visible after clicking away` ...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Forgot about expect in last line.
Solution:
`welcome.expect.element('@logoutButton').to.not.be.present`